# How could react-native-web use react-native import?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

How could we import react-native when it's not installed on dependency when using react-native-web? The sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6

Answer (score 1):

open your link and File->new sandbox -> [select react]
clicke "add dependency" button and add dependency

react-native
react-native-web
and ...